# What did I do wrong in this proof?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I have this answer marked partially correct. I'd like to get an idea of where I went wrong

**Prove that for all integers $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$, $(a+b)^5 \equiv a^5+b^5 \mod 5$.**

*My answer:*

Suppose that $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, by definition of congruence modulo, $5|(a+b)^5-(a^5+b^5)$ meaning that there exists an integer $k$ such that $$(a+b)^5-(a^5+b^5)=5k$$ Then, $$a^5+5a^4b+10a^3b^2+10a^2b^3+5b^4a+b^5-a^5-b^5 = 5k$$ $$= 5(a^4b+2a^3b^2+2a^2b^3+b^4)=5k$$
This shows that the deduced result is divisible by 5, hence, for all integer $a,b,\in\mathbb{Z}$, $(a+b)^5 \equiv a^5+b^5 \mod 5$.

Comment: You need to show that $5|(a+b)^5-(a^5+b^5)$, you can't start by using that.

Comment: So how would I go about proving that then? If that's the statement, why can't I use the definition of congruence module and then deduce that this is true?

Comment: It's the old fallacy of affirming the consequent: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_the_consequent .

Comment: Simply cut out the first two lines and the formula that follows them. Go with $(a+b)^5 -a^5-b^5 = a^5+5a^4b+...-a^5-b^5 =...= 5k$ which proves your fact.

Comment: By the way, this can be generalized for any prime number $p$. That is, for any prime $p$ and any integers $a$ and $b$ you have $p \mid (a+b)^p-a^p-b^p$. To prove that it suffices to notice that binomial coefficients $p\choose k$, $0<k<p$, are divisible by $p$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your idea is correct, but your proof looks backwards. I suggest the following modifications. Observe how now the proof looks like a tale of deduction rather than one of back-engineering, if you may.

> Suppose that $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$. Then, by definition of congruence
>   modulo, **we must show that** $5|(a+b)^5-(a^5+b^5)$. **This means**
>   that there exists an integer $k$ such that $$(a+b)^5-(a^5+b^5)=5k$$ 
>   **Let us show this holds. To see this, note that**, $$(a+b)^5 = a^5+5a^4b+10a^3b^2+10a^2b^3+5b^4a+b^5 = a^5+b^5+5k$$
>
> **where $a^4b+2a^3b^2+2a^2b^3+b^4=k$ is obtained by collecting terms.** This shows that **the difference $(a+b)^5 -a^5-b^5$** is divisible by 5, hence,
>   for all integer $a,b,\in\mathbb{Z}$, $(a+b)^5 \equiv a^5+b^5 \mod 5$.

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though you're starting from what you want to prove, although this is not the case. I think it would be clearer if you started with just the LHS of the expression and showing that you can find a factorization of $5k$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. You should also argue that the expression $a^4b+2a^3b^2+2a^2b^3+b^4$ is an integer.

Comment: What do you mean by this? How would I go about fixing my current proof?

Comment: Essentially you would repeat the same process, but leave off the $5k$. Expand the polynomial, cancel terms, and factor out the $5$. Then show that your final result is indeed $5$ times an integer, which proves the claim.